# ActionbarSherlock getting Actionbar size

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I'm using ActionbarSherlock 4.3.1 for compatibility to API 8. I use an overlay Actionbar:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {               
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...
```

I have an `ImageView` that fills the entire screen, including under the Actionbar (which is semi-transparent, like Google Maps). I use a `RelativeLayout` for drawing a button overlay on top of the `ImageView`. The RelativeLayout is offset vertically by the Actionbar size using `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` to that the top row of buttons appear just beneath the Actionbar.

The vertical offset works great on ICS and on, but not for Gingerbread (haven't tested HC or Froyo), where the buttons (which should appear just vertically below below the Actionbar) are covered up by the Actionbar and not vertically shifted downward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the `RelativeLayout` must set `android:layout_gravity="top"` to make `layout_marginTop` work.